# Connectivity Change Broadcast receiver not triggering when phone is in sleep mode

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sleep-mode

I have a network state change `Broadcast Receiver` setup for my app. I need to receive wifi connect-disconnect events even when phone is in sleep mode. This works when phone is charging and in sleep, but doesn't when its not in sleep.

here is code

```
public class NetworkConnectionReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
public static final String INTENT_CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE = "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(INTENT_CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE)) {
        NetworkChangedEvent event = new NetworkChangedEvent();
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
        boolean wifiConnected = activeNetworkInfo != null
                && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected()
                && activeNetworkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI;

        if (wifiConnected) {
            // start a service here
        } 
    }
}
}
```

here is how its registered in manifest

```
 <receiver
        android:name=".NetworkConnectionReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I am aware of doze mode related issue in Marshmallow and above devices but I am not even receiving events in Kitkat devices when phone is in sleep and its not connected to charger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [WakefulBroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html):

> Helper for the common pattern of implementing a BroadcastReceiver that receives a device wakeup event and then passes the work off to a Service, while ensuring that the device does not go back to sleep during the transition.
>
> This class takes care of creating and managing a partial wake lock for you; you must request the WAKE_LOCK permission to use it.

Comment: trying this right now but I am not sure as I think that Broadcast itself is not triggering in first place.

Comment: Update: It works on one device while not on another. Accepting answer for now.