# Monitor WiFi sleep mode events

Tags: android, connectivity, android-broadcastreceiver, android-wake-lock, sleep-mode

I have to monitor the connectivity of the device automatically, to do that I have my receiver registered with

```
<receiver android:name=".NetworkStateReceiver" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE"/>
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.supplicant.CONNECTION_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

It works fine, but when the WiFi goes to sleep mode, the network info will have the state DISCONNECTED/BLOCKED. This is ok, I understand why it does this to save battery etc.

The issue is that the receiver doesn't receive an intent when the WiFi goes to sleep mode. Same thing if I wake up the device, the WiFi will switch to connected state but I won't receive an intent.

(Tested on a Nexus 5X)

Any way I could receive those events without having to use an alarm that would fire every X minutes to check the state?

Checked [Connectivity Change Broadcast receiver not triggering when phone is in sleep mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41057584/connectivity-change-broadcast-receiver-not-triggering-when-phone-is-in-sleep-mod?rq=1) but answer seems irrelevant

Comment: which targetSdkVersion are you using?

Comment: min version is 10, target will be the latest.
My nexus has latest version, I managed to get the events by listening to the android.os.action.DEVICE_IDLE_MODE_CHANGED intent. I'll test to check whether the behavior is the same on pre M devices

Comment: The thing is that since M version you are not receiving wifi events while your application is not on foreground

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32151603/scan-results-available-action-return-empty-list-in-android-6-0

Comment: ?? Where is this coming from? My broadcast does receive the intent when the app is in the background (al registered in manifest)